# Some RS fields are left as zeros whereas others are not (ADODB)

Tags: c#, mysql, adodb, visual-studio-2019

I am working on a C# sales point project and one of the tasks the program is supposed to do is have a layaway system where a customer can order an item we currently don't have but can get it for them if they pay an advancement.

The layaway is then placed on a table in a database with the items' information as well as the customer's information to contact them when the items are ready.

The program works, to an extent. I am getting a problem when getting the data from a MySQL table: Numeric items are displayed as zeros while non numeric items are displayed correctly, and I don't know why this is happening.

Can anyone please help me? Thanks!

```
public string[] detalleAnticipoPorId(int idAnticipo)
    {
        string[] detalleAnticipo = new string[7];
        deleteParameters();
        object objRecAff = Type.Missing;
        Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ref_anticipos WHERE ant_id = ? ";
        Cmd.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText;
        object objParameters = Type.Missing;
        ADODB.Parameter numParam = Cmd.CreateParameter("NoPedido", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 50, idAnticipo);
        Cmd.Parameters.Append(numParam);
        rs = Cmd.Execute(out objRecAff, ref objParameters, 0);
        detalleAnticipo[0] = rs.Fields["ant_id"].Value.ToString(); //Gives out zero rather than number as string
        detalleAnticipo[1] = rs.Fields["ant_id_cliente"].Value.ToString(); //same here
        detalleAnticipo[2] = rs.Fields["ant_fecha_creada"].Value.ToString();
        detalleAnticipo[3] = rs.Fields["ant_monto_pagado"].Value.ToString();
        detalleAnticipo[4] = rs.Fields["ant_estatus"].Value.ToString();
        detalleAnticipo[5] = rs.Fields["ant_id_pedido"].Value.ToString(); //and here
        detalleAnticipo[6] = rs.Fields["ant_nota"].Value.ToString();

        return detalleAnticipo;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using ADODB rather than ADO.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Cmd.Execute` method is returning a record set, yet you aren't advancing to the first record before you attempt to read the data.

You'll need to `rs.Read()` before you can read the values, and then maybe `rs.GetString(0)` (with the field ordinal) to get the values.

You'll probably also want to check `rs.RecordCount` first, to make sure you actually got a result to your query.